# muti line text with first line underline in datagridviewTextBoxCell Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm able to add the mutiline text in datagridViewtextboxcell by using Environment.NewLine while inserting. but I would like to add underline for 1st line. so how could i achive this in vb.net

now I'm handling the paint method of DGV for showing date in 2 color for date format(as like in first column).

Please find the attached image,
[image]

in that second last column for email and cell number i want to draw underline.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question.
Handle the DataGridView1_CellPainting and call this method for specific cell/column.firstly seperate the string and render it with TextRenderer class 2 times with new location.

I don't know is this correct way, but it works.

```
Private Sub CellText_Underline(color As Color, e As DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs)

    Dim text As String = e.FormattedValue.ToString()

    Dim nameParts As String() = text.Split(" ")

    Dim topLeft As New Point(e.CellBounds.X, CInt(e.CellBounds.Y + (e.CellBounds.Height / 4)))

    Dim arialBold As New Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Regular Xor FontStyle.Underline)

    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, nameParts(0), arialBold, topLeft, color)

    Dim topLeft_1 As New Point(e.CellBounds.X, CInt(e.CellBounds.Y + (e.CellBounds.Height / 4) + 5))
    Dim s As Size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(nameParts(0), arialBold)
    Dim p As New Point(topLeft_1.X, topLeft_1.Y + 12)

    Dim arialBold_1 As New Font("Arial", 11, FontStyle.Regular)
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, nameParts(1), arialBold_1, p, SystemColors.WindowText)
End Sub
```

Thanks.